# Как правильно произносить чешские имена Петр и Алена

Tags: орфоэпия

скажите как в России произносить чешские имена А́лена Врза́нёва чешское произношение: [ˈalɛna vrzaːɲovaː] (чеш. Alena Vrzáňová), и  Петр Чех (чеш. Petr Čech) чешское произношение: [ˈpɛtr ˈtʃɛx], ну наверное не Алёна и Пётр, если через Е записываются в русский язык по правилам чешско-русской транскрипции, то Алена или Алэна, Петр или Пэтр их произносить в русском языке через Е или через Э должны правильно звучать, скажите как всё-таки правильно? Например чешское имя Марек, произносят через Э МарЭк с ударением на А.Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В русском языке принято по возможности не коверкать имена людей, поэтому в данном случае, как правило, читается без *ё.* "Как правило" я добавил, так как ошибка при первом прочтении очень вероятна, так как русские имена Алёна и Пётр тоже часто пишут через *е.*

Что же касается произнесения, то Э в русском языке после твёрдого согласного произносится в очень небольшом списке односложных слов. Единственное исключение, которое вспомнил, "тестер", но и оно образовано от односложного "тест".

Comment: Ну а произносить-то чешские имена Алена и Петр нужно всё-таки через Е или через Э в русском языке? Петр или ПЭтр, Алена или АлЭна? В чешском в этих именах разве  не звук Э?

Comment: По правилам чешско-русской транскрипции они записаны через Е , как Алена и Петр, а читаются наверное всё-таки через Э ПЭтр, АлЭна(ударение на `А), как например чешское имя Марек записан с буквой Е, а произносить-то  правильно не МАрек а М`АрЭк?

Comment: Наверное правильно озвучить не Алена как записано имя, а АлЭна с ударением на `А, и не Петр как записано, а ПЭтр

Comment: @SwarogSvetogor Э в русском языке после твёрдого согласного произносится в очень небольшом списке односложных слов. Единственное исключение, которое вспомнил "тестер", но и оно образовано от односложного "тест". Так что чешские Алена и Петр как пишутся, так и читаются.

Comment: Какой-то не логичный у вас ответ, причём тут правила русской орфографии и орфоэпии, имена собственные тем более иностранные неподчиняются никаким правилам, написание следует из чешско-русской транскрипции, весь вопрос в том как озвучить эти имена по-русски, так как они произносятся в чешском языке или как записаны в русском, какие звуки е/э в чешских именах Алена и Петр